# Exception while reading content of a document in MarkLogic

Tags: marklogic

When I try to read a text document from MarkLogic database using it's URI..I get get below specified exception:

```
[Fatal Error] :1:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
Exception in thread "main" com.marklogic.client.FailedRequestException: Local message: read failed: Bad Request. Server Message: Request failed. Unable to parse server error details
    at com.marklogic.client.impl.JerseyServices.getDocumentImpl(JerseyServices.java:527)
    at com.marklogic.client.impl.JerseyServices.getDocument(JerseyServices.java:393)
    at com.marklogic.client.impl.DocumentManagerImpl.read(DocumentManagerImpl.java:210)
    at com.marklogic.client.impl.DocumentManagerImpl.read(DocumentManagerImpl.java:144)
    at com.marklogic.client.impl.DocumentManagerImpl.read(DocumentManagerImpl.java:114)
    at com.marklogic.client.example.tutorial.Example_07_ReadText.main(Example_07_ReadText.java:49)
```

Comment: What's in the document?

Answer (score 2):

User3569076:

It sounds like the request is failing but the Java API can't parse the error message because the error message isn't XML.

When you create the database client, are you specifying the hostname and port for a REST API server?

If not, here are the instructions for creating a REST API server for a database:

http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/service#id_12021

You can test the availability of the REST API by trying to get a document from the host and port in your web browser:

http://docs.marklogic.com/REST/GET/v1/documents

Hoping that helps,

Erik Hennum

Comment: Yes hostname and port number for MarkLogic server were specified correctly and I was able to fetch URIs of most of the documents when I specified one of the directory. But after changing that directory to some other directory I was getting above specified error.
But right now unfortunately I am not getting that same error, so can't share exact scenario. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error while loading a JSON file in MarkLogic database.
I found that the error was that my JSON file wasn't valid. There were some syntax errors in my JSON file.
What I could recommend you to do is that you check if your XML file is valid.

Hope this will be helpfull.